# Why would two sub-panels be cross-connected?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a house with 2 main 200 amp panels. These will need to be replaced as the are Federal Pacific. Each panel has its own 200 amp main breaker. I am in the process of tracking down what wires go where and it appears that the 2 panels are cross connected by a 30 amp 2 pole breaker in each.

Why would you do this and isn't this dangerous?

The wire in question is:
Left box second black cable on top right
Right box far/first right cable on top right

[image]

Comment: If you can, please provide a picture or two.

Comment: I am not sure why anyone would do this unless it was for back feeding the 2nd panel.

Comment: Is there anything on the circuit besides this cross connection? Like does the wiring actually power a plug (dryer or stove) or appliance (air conditioner) somewhere?

Comment: That huge box in the middle is not normal. What can you tell us about it?  Also, where is your electric meter?

Comment: That huge box in the middle seems to receive the main service and feeds it to the other two panels? Please provide one picture per panel opened up.

Comment: WOW & Yikes.  Announcement: Cleanup needed is aisle 5.  

Seriously though, the big box in middle might contain CT (Current Transformer) metering equipment to provide a true 400 amp service.  But I don't see a POCO lockout tag on it, so I'm not sure.   

Also, the 30 amp cross connect might be there if one of the panels could be supplied by a generator and then the other panel get power from it.  If so, without the proper physical lock mechanisms that prevent generator power from feeding back into the network.... That is all very very sketchy.

Comment: The big box in the middle does have some lock out tabs on it. The electric meter is outside just above this area and I believe is fed via the rigid conduit. Yes serious cleanup on aisle 5, 6, 7 and 8! I've 'pruned' the old base board wiring as they have been removed. I will update pictures tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Pictures of the 2 panels will help a lot. Also, before Harper and then others get a chance, I'll tell you: For the replacement panels, get **really big panels**. The reasons include AFCI, GFCI and the possibility of adding new circuits or splitting existing circuits. Since your panels are not stuck in finished walls, you have plenty of room to work with.

Comment: Pictures of the labeling on the  big box would be a help too. Do you want to DIY these panel replacements, and if so, would  you be amenable to having the meter changed out to a meter-main?  That may allow the huge box to go away altogether.  Also, any future aspirations for a generator?

Comment: I will take some pictures of the big box and the meter. I am not sure as to the routing of feed though they are underground and I can see a transformer box in my neighbor's yard. A generator interface would be great and now would be the time to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Could we get a photo of the panels with the doors open Federal pacific  made more than 1 panel and to my knowledge “stablock” panels were the only ones that had issues. The other panels were made prior to stablock.  Lucky for you those will be easy updates how high is the main breaker off the floor? As far as the clean up comment it is not bad today it needs to be covered but other than 1 piece of Romex stripped two far back all the power wiring looks fine the mess is in the low voltage / telecom but even there I have seen much worse pass inspection.

Comment: @EdBeal There is a conduit coming into the top of that large box,  could it be 600 volts and there is an actual transformer in there as opposed to CT metering transformers?  I don't see any venting for heat generated by a true transformer.

Comment: A 400a transformer no way they are large. Think minimum of 50kw for a utility transformer, yes I know that 400 amps is closer to 100kw but the utilities don’t have to play by the same rules we do quite often they drop a 50kw  my last place I smoked a 50 on a true 400 feed and they put a 75kw in it held just fine with 3 of us in the shop seeing if it would hold. that is the size of a standard ct cabinet